# Windows net stop start not working in bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following script in a bat file. If I run NET STOP "XXX" and NET START "XXX", it will work. But when I execute the bat file, it does not restart the service as I expected. The log file however was renamed. I have tried to run the bat file as administrator but still no good.

```
@echo off

findstr /m "memory" "C:\Services\ServiceLogs\NZTA_OnTheMove_AlertSender.log"
if %errorlevel%==0 (


NET STOP "Jericho NZTA Alert Sender"

timeout 30

NET START "Jericho NZTA Alert Sender"

set HR=%time:~0,2%
set HR=%Hr: =0% 
set HR=%HR: =%

rename "C:\Services\ServiceLogs\NZTA_OnTheMove_AlertSender.log" "NZTA_OnTheMove_AlertSender_%date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%_%HR%%time:~3,2%.err"

)
```

Comment: The batch file was not successfully copy/pasted into your question, it is showing up as all one line.  Please edit it and try again.

Comment: You know, I suspect this error is still caused by the second line, program is reading the log file. If it does not run into any problem, then it will proceed to the stop and start service logic.

Comment: Well, is it finding the word "memory" in the file?  It will only run the other commands if it does.

Comment: That is one piece of excellent comment. Wondering why would they put that logic there....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After bypassing the logic findstr /m "memory" "C:\Services\ServiceLogs\NZTA_OnTheMove_AlertSender.log"
if %errorlevel%==0
Script works again.